# CMake 3.10 not working at all with Visual Studio 2015, 2017

Tags: c++11, compiler-errors, compilation, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to compile two different git projects via CMake.
I have Visual Studio 2017 Community, MinGW and CodeBlocks installed and CMake throws an error with all of them. Keep in mind I have not used CMake before.

With "Visual Studio 15 2017 selected I get this error:

```
The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.12.25835.0
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.12.25835.0
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.12.25827/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.12.25827/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.12.25827/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.12.25827/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
Build type: Release
Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11
Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11 - Failed
Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X
Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X - Failed
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:26 (message):
  The compiler C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual
  Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.12.25827/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe has
  no C++11 support.  Please use a different C++ compiler.
```

With "MinGW Makefiles" selected I get a cc1.exe errors about a bunch of ddls. Sadly the popup error messages are in german even though I've set everything in Win10 to english so I dont know what they say exactly.

With "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" I get the same as above.

Link to one of the git projects Im trying to compile:

https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2
https://github.com/YutaItoh/3D-Eye-Tracker

By the way, I tried the same with VS 2015 previously.

Content of the CMakeLists file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(ORB_SLAM2)

IF(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
ENDIF()

MESSAGE("Build type: " ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}  -Wall  -O3 -march=native ")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall   -O3 -march=native")

# Check C++11 or C++0x support
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++11" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++0x" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
   add_definitions(-DCOMPILEDWITHC11)
   message(STATUS "Using flag -std=c++11.")
elseif(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")
   add_definitions(-DCOMPILEDWITHC0X)
   message(STATUS "Using flag -std=c++0x.")
else()
   message(FATAL_ERROR "The compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} has no C++11 support. Please use a different C++ compiler.")
endif()

LIST(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules)

find_package(OpenCV 3.0 QUIET)
if(NOT OpenCV_FOUND)
   find_package(OpenCV 2.4.3 QUIET)
   if(NOT OpenCV_FOUND)
      message(FATAL_ERROR "OpenCV > 2.4.3 not found.")
   endif()
endif()

find_package(Eigen3 3.1.0 REQUIRED)
find_package(Pangolin REQUIRED)

include_directories(
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}
${Pangolin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
src/System.cc
src/Tracking.cc
src/LocalMapping.cc
src/LoopClosing.cc
src/ORBextractor.cc
src/ORBmatcher.cc
src/FrameDrawer.cc
src/Converter.cc
src/MapPoint.cc
src/KeyFrame.cc
src/Map.cc
src/MapDrawer.cc
src/Optimizer.cc
src/PnPsolver.cc
src/Frame.cc
src/KeyFrameDatabase.cc
src/Sim3Solver.cc
src/Initializer.cc
src/Viewer.cc
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
${OpenCV_LIBS}
${EIGEN3_LIBS}
${Pangolin_LIBRARIES}
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Thirdparty/DBoW2/lib/libDBoW2.so
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Thirdparty/g2o/lib/libg2o.so
)

# Build examples

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Examples/RGB-D)

add_executable(rgbd_tum
Examples/RGB-D/rgbd_tum.cc)
target_link_libraries(rgbd_tum ${PROJECT_NAME})

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Examples/Stereo)

add_executable(stereo_kitti
Examples/Stereo/stereo_kitti.cc)
target_link_libraries(stereo_kitti ${PROJECT_NAME})

add_executable(stereo_euroc
Examples/Stereo/stereo_euroc.cc)
target_link_libraries(stereo_euroc ${PROJECT_NAME})


set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Examples/Monocular)

add_executable(mono_tum
Examples/Monocular/mono_tum.cc)
target_link_libraries(mono_tum ${PROJECT_NAME})

add_executable(mono_kitti
Examples/Monocular/mono_kitti.cc)
target_link_libraries(mono_kitti ${PROJECT_NAME})

add_executable(mono_euroc
Examples/Monocular/mono_euroc.cc)
target_link_libraries(mono_euroc ${PROJECT_NAME})
```

Comment: 1) Please, quote relevant excerpts of the main CMakeLists file here. Links to external resources are likely to break in the future. 2) How do you call CMake? Looks like your CMake mixes up MSVC versions. 3) AFAIK CMake 3.1 does not support VS2017. Try with a recent CMake, e.g. 3.9.

Comment: 1) done, 2) I use cmake-gui and select "Visual Studio 15 2017" in the dropdown menu, 3) sorry, I have Cmake 3.10, not 3.1

Comment: comment updated

Comment: The C++11 capability check will always fail with MSVC. Use CMake's CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD variable.

Comment: Where is that ?

Comment: The lines following `# Check C++11 or C++0x support` represent the old (i.e. pre CMake 3.x) style of checking for compiler or language features. It does not respect the command line flags of MSVC. Use [`CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html) and let CMake handle all the compiler specific stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The C++11 capability check will always fail with MSVC. Use CMake's CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD variable.